# Convertir fragmento de CSS a LESS

Tags: css, less

Quiero pasar este CSS a LESS, ¿Cómo quedaría en LESS?

```
.Item {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 259px;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.Item-name {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 45px;  
  display: -o-inline-box;
}
.Item-price {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.12em;      
}
```

Comment: Ya es `.less` válido :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En less seria así:

```
.Item {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 259px;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    &-name {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        height: 45px;  
        display: -o-inline-box;
    }
    &-price {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.12em; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿hay alguna ventaja por tener anidados así los estilos? Supongo que da sensación de estructura pero, personalmente, a mí me resultan más difíciles de leer

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro igual esto le ayude -> http://michelletorres.mx/ventajas-del-uso-de-less/ en el apartado Anidado: .Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Ya que LESS es un superconjunto de CSS es decir la sintaxis de CSS es válida en LESS

Tu código

```
.Item {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 259px;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.Item-name {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 45px;  
  display: -o-inline-box;
}
.Item-price {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.12em;      
}
```

Quedaría así en LESS

```
.Item {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 259px;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.Item-name {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 45px;  
  display: -o-inline-box;
}
.Item-price {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.12em;      
}
```

Es decir no requiere modificación alguna. =)

Ahora bien si lo que quieres es aprovechar las ventajes de LESS frente a CSS puedes hacerlo como [la respuesta de Daniel Hernández](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2956/convertir-fragmento-de-css-a-less/2957#2957)